# Enforcing Java Security Policy based on signedBy

Tags: java, permissions, code-signing, security-policy, java-security-manager

I'm trying to enforce a security policy, giving Java classes signed by a certain signer certain permissions. My security policy file looks as following:

```
// ========== SYSTEM CODE PERMISSIONS =========================================
grant codeBase "file:${java.home}/conf/*" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

// These permissions apply to all shared system extensions
grant codeBase "file:${java.home}/jre/lib/ext/*" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

// These permissions apply to all shared system extensions
grant codeBase "file:${java.home}/lib/ext/*" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};


// ========== CLASS PERMISSIONS =========================================
keystore "file:/C:/Program Files/Java/openjdk-12/lib/security/cacerts";
keystorePasswordURL "file:/C:/Shared/Team/java-jar-signed/keystore.password";
grant signedBy "mycompany" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\*", "read,write,execute";
    permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\", "read,write,execute";
};
```

The Keystore `cacerts` contains a certificate with the alias `mycompany`. The JAR file im testing the security policy with has been signed with the private key of that certificate. When I execute the JAR file with

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=rules.policy -Djava.security.debug=access -cp ReadC-signed.jar ReadC
```

I get

```
access: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\" "read")
```

When I use `codeBase "path/to/jar"` instead of `signedBy "mycompany"` it works perfectly fine. Does anybody know what could be going wrong here?